# Installing on a laptop with a broken screen - how can I duplicate the display to an external monitor rather than extending it before installation?

Tags: unity, system-installation, display

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop which has a broken LCD.

I've plugged it into a monitor via HDMI but it is extending my screen instead of duplicating it, leading to the install icon being on the broken LCD and I'm assuming that the terminal windows I am trying to open are opening on there as well.

I've tried using <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> keys to no avail.

Comment: Check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/461553/which-command-line-commands-enable-mirror-feature-in-the-screen-display-gui

Comment: Also use CTRL+ALT+F1 to get the terminal on your HDMI.

Comment: have you tried disabling your built in LCD from bios?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you will want to do is to press your <kbd>super_key</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

on your keyboard, your super key is likely the windows key.

every time you do it will cycle through

- Extended display
- Duplicate display
- Display attached screen/projector only
- Native (laptop/desktop) screen only

As noted in the second answer for this question 
[How to have duplicate display on ubuntu 14.04 with gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697018/how-to-have-duplicate-display-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-gnome)

let us know if that works for you.

Comment: I've also tried this, is there a way for me to install Ubuntu without having to boot into the trial?

Comment: @JamesHudson when you boot the usb, you will have the options "try ubuntu without installing" and "install ubuntu"... select the latter

Comment: It has been bringing me directly to the trial, is there a key combo I have to press during the Ubuntu loading screen?

Comment: @JamesHudson do you know if you got the option that Joshua is referring to? because you should be, then you should be able to select the options by using <kbd>tab</kbd> or arrow keys. You may not see the option if they are on the broken screen.

Comment: @JamesHudson you want to install Ubuntu. you got the mirroring of screen by above answer. then from "try ubuntu" option you can install Ubuntu know. if you really want to select "Install Ubuntu" option you need to guess the time and press the down arrow and up arrow in keyboard while booting to stop the countdown. Then after some time keep the up arrow many times. so that you are on "Try Ubuntu Option" highlighted. now press the down arrow to highlight "Install Ubuntu" option and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

After several reboots the installation window appeared on my external monitor, not 100% sure why but I'll take it as a victory, thanks for all the responses!